# Typeset problem and Texshop crash on Mac El Capitan

Tags: errors

I recently downloaded LaTex to write my bachelor thesis. I tried it out using Yosemite and it seemed to work fine. Just updated to El Capitan and now I don't get a preview when I use the typeset and save my document. I've tried changing the path setting to `Library/Tex/texbin`. Still doesn't work. Furthermore, when I try to close the TeXShop window it just crashes. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome! Is everything up-to-date? TeXShop? Mac TeX?

Comment: Yes everything is up to date. Tried reinstalling MacTex2015 and also updated Texshop to v. 3.54. I already checked some of the other questions about problems with El Capitan but I found nothing useful.

Comment: Thomas, did you find a solution to your problem? I am having the same problem and don't know what to do.